# No wireless connection after installing OpenSUSE 12.3

Tags: wireless-networking, installation, opensuse

I just installed OpenSUSE 12.3 on my laptop with Gnome. I'm unable to connect to any wifi. I don't even have the "Wireless" submenu on the top right of my screen. All I have is the "Wired" submenu. I tried a lot of things but without success. I have something like that when I enter "sudo /sbin/ifconfig" :

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:95 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:95 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:9691 (9.4 Kb)  TX bytes:9691 (9.4 Kb)

p1p1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A4:BA:DB:CC:16:19  
      inet addr:192.168.1.9  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:316 (316.0 b)  TX bytes:3768 (3.6 Kb)
```

Earlier I tried to manually add a vlan0 interface from the YaST, but I still wouldn't get any IP on this interface.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Was perusing either of these pages http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.wireless.wlan.html - http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.nm.html part of that lot of thing you tried without success?

Comment: I did read these pages. But if you take a look at this part : http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.nm.html#sec.nm.configure you'll see that they are to configure a wireless network from the network manager. The problem is I don't even have the "wireless" submenu.

Comment: So, then the problem appears to be that OpenSUSE 12.3 doesn't recognize your wireless card at all... as in it doesn't think you have one.  At this point, I think knowing the make/model of your laptop and specifically the make/model of your wireless card would be important.

Comment: I have a Dell Vostro 3700 and my wifi card is a "Broadcom Corporation BCM43224". I installed the following package to ensure I have the right driver : "broadcom-wl". Does it help?

Comment: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/447485-bcm43224-bcm43225-bcm4313-installation-guide-3.html You apparently have to install the drivers for the card specifically.... and there appear to be issues in general with Broadcom.  Recommendation as per that thread is to use the official Broadcom drivers http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

Comment: It worked !!! Thank you @BonGart. I just downloaded the files and followed the instructions of the readme. This link has been very helpful too: http://www.mindwerks.net/2011/11/wireless-bcm4312-3-2-kernel/

Comment: I'll condense the comments into an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was perusing either of [these](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.wireless.wlan.html) [pages](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.nm.html) part of that lot of thing you tried without success?  If so, then the problem appears to be that OpenSUSE 12.3 doesn't recognize your wireless card at all... as in it doesn't think you have one.  [As per this thread](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/447485-bcm43224-bcm43225-bcm4313-installation-guide-3.html), you apparently have to install the drivers for the card specifically, and there appear to be issues in general with Broadcom.  Recommendation as per that thread is to use the [official Broadcom drivers](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php).

Comment: I just had to download the official drivers and install them by folowing the instructions of the readme and this link was also helpful : http://www.mindwerks.net/2011/11/wireless-bcm4312-3-2-kernel/ Thanks again :-)